# Python: Tkinter button function and urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, urllib2

Alright so I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh6AdDX7K7U) tutorial on Python GUIs with `Tkinter`.

My code is below and everything works fine. However this is not accurate since the program doesn't do what I actually need.

In the GUIs box I want the user to be able to provide a link that will then be used from `urllib2` to grab some links from the web and then open them via the drop-down menu of my GUI.

So far, the link that the user is supposed to provide is hard-coded into the source and the button does pretty much nothing.

So what I need here is to be able to connect the my button with `response = urllib2.urlopen`?

Any thoughs on that? Thanks a lot.

```
import urllib2
from Tkinter import *
#import tkinter.messagebox
#import turtle

#fetching uris from the web
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/..')
html = response.read()
with open("/path/to/URIs.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(html)


def ChangeLabel():
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/..')
    labelText.set(response)
    #yourName.delete(0, END)
    html = response.read()
    #yourName.insert(0, html)
    return

def aboutMe():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Hello there!')
    return

def openURIS():
    f = open("/path/to/URIs.txt")
    aboutStud.delete(1.0, END)

    studGradeString = ""

    for i in f:
            studGradeString += i

    aboutStud.insert(END, studGradeString)
    f.close()
    return

app = Tk()
app.title('Simple Tkinter GUI')
app.geometry('400x500')

menubar = Menu(app)
filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open URIs", command=openURIS)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=app.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)


helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_cascade(label="About us", command=aboutMe)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

app.config(menu=menubar)

aboutStud = Text(app)
aboutStud.insert(END, "Paste link into the little box to fetch URIs")
aboutStud.pack()

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set('Click button below')
label1 = Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=4)
label1.pack()

#checkBoxVal = IntVar()
#checkBox1 = Checkbutton(app, variable=checkBoxVal, text="Hello?")
#checkBox1.pack()

custom = StringVar(None)
legend = Entry(app, textvariable=custom)
legend.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text='Click to fetch URIs', width=20, command=ChangeLabel)
button1.pack(side='top', padx=15 , pady=15)

app.mainloop()
```

There are also many lines that I should change or even delete but I am planning to do this once I understand better the code and how it works.

Comment: But you already have connection between `Button` and function (with line `response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/..')`) because you have `command=ChangeLabel`

Comment: pasting the url into the box and clicking the button just prompts an error. I will edit and show it in my question. I know there is already a connection between the two but not the one I want. Its a mess tbh

Comment: So put the one inside `ChangeLabel`

Comment: And alwayse add full error message in python. There are number of line with problem - mark that line in code.

Comment: I need the URI to be user input and not hard-coded thats the main problem here. How should I do that?

Comment: If user inputs URL then you have it in `custom`. You only have to get it `custom.get()` and use in `urllib2.urlopen()`. Read [Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) - maybe it's old but still the best.

Comment: Along with some other changes, `custom.get` inside the `urllib2.urlopen()` worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user inputs URL then you have it in `custom`. You only have to get it `custom.get()` and use in `urllib2.urlopen()`. Read [Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) - maybe it's old but still the best.